# Calling JS method from Rails Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So this is my controller function.

```
def fb_close
  current_user.update_user_points(SHARE_POINT_ONE, message, current_user.id, 0) if params[:post_id].present?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :js => "my_function();" }
  end
end
```

and im trying to go back a js function called my_function inside script tag on the same page. I'm getting an error like `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

I want to know where i was wrong. Please correct me.

I have a file named fb_close.html.erb i can get the call to that file.. Is there any way i can link it with a js function

Comment: From where and how are you calling fb_close action? What is the URL?

Comment: You should be better putting the code of `my_function` in a separate file of format `js` and call it like `format.js { render 'your_file_name' }`

Comment: Wold not be simpler to just create a `fb_close.js.erb` view and call there `my_function();` ???

Comment: @Octopus-Paul yea i did that..still im experiencing the same error

Comment: can you let us know what is the url you are trying to call as you have to call your action with .js postfix like so http://localhost:3000/controller/action.js

Answer (score 2):

You should be better putting the code of `my_function` in a separate file of format `js` and call it like `format.js { render 'your_file_name' }`

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render 'your_file_name' }
end
```

You have to create a file like `fb_close.js.erb` and put the code of `my_function` in it and call it like this

```
respond_to do |format|
format.js { render 'fb_close' }
end
```

Comment: @NidhinSG What is the file name you created?

Comment: i got fb_close.html.erb file inside which i have placed a code like <% p"------" %>
it was shown in terminal.. Is there any way i can load a script file inside that page then?

Comment: @NidhinSG Where do you have the code of `my_fucntion`? Try moving the code of my_function to separate file like `fb_close.js.erb` and call it as like this.

Comment: I told u there is no call going to that function.. im getting an eror..ActionController::UnknownFormat I did like what you said

Comment: @NidhinSG What are you trying to do? I you want call the function `my_function`,do as i said or if you want render just html file,change it to `format.html { render 'fb_close' }` and file name should be just `fb_close.html.erb`.

Comment: im not able to get the render the js.. If i dont write anything the call automaticaly goes to fb_close.html.erb
if i write respond to do.. i get a format error..